# why am i getting TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df.dates, errors='coerce')
d1 = pd.to_timedelta(d1).dt.days
```

i have lots of dates in a column which i want to convert to number of days but i simply keep getting errors. im new to pandas so sorry if the question is silly

```
2014-07-29
2008-11-14
2010-04-20
2011-08-31
2002-07-29
2013-10-29
```

but why am i getting errors and how to fix them.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-298bf748984e> in <module>()
      1 d1 = pd.to_datetime(df.dates, errors='coerce')
----> 2 d1 = pd.to_timedelta(d1).dt.days

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/timedeltas.py in to_timedelta(arg, unit, errors)
    122         return arg
    123     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
--> 124         values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, unit=unit, errors=errors)
    125         return arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    126     elif isinstance(arg, ABCIndex):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/timedeltas.py in _convert_listlike(arg, unit, errors, name)
    171 
    172     try:
--> 173         td64arr = sequence_to_td64ns(arg, unit=unit, errors=errors, copy=False)[0]
    174     except ValueError:
    175         if errors == "ignore":

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/timedeltas.py in sequence_to_td64ns(data, copy, unit, errors)
   1018     else:
   1019         # This includes datetime64-dtype, see GH#23539, GH#29794
-> 1020         raise TypeError(f"dtype {data.dtype} cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]")
   1021 
   1022     data = np.array(data, copy=copy)

TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of days to now, use:

```
today = pd.Timestamp.today().normalize()
d1 = (today - pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], errors='coerce')).dt.days
print(d1)

# Output
0    2910
1    4993
2    4471
3    3973
4    7293
5    3183
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

Comment: this solved my problem but this poses another question to me, if i want to instead of today's date have it to a far future date and year, like 2025-01-01 and subtract, how can i do it

Comment: Use `today = pd.Timestamp('2025-01-01')`

Answer (score 1):

@Corralien's solution is great! I just wanted to add some context for learning purposes:

Notice that it returns a `TypeError` because the method `timedelta` is meant to be applied to a range of time, a delta. In Pandas "linguo" it is a `datetimelike` value.  So if you pass regular dates to it, the error you got is somewhat expected.

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html), you can see that the TypeError is mentioned right at the bottom.

Try this out to see the types you get:

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], errors='coerce')
print(d1.dtype)
print(type(d1))
print(type(d1.iloc[0]))
```

Then this should be the result:

```
datetime64[ns]
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

Thus:

```
TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]
```